# TeXStudio: disable internal shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+X)

Tags: texstudio, characters, french

I'm using a french keyboard with a bepo layout which makes great use of the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key modifier.

Unfortunately, some of TeXStudio's shortcuts use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier. I managed to disable almost all conflicting shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>).

However, I can't disable one last shortcut: in TeXStudio, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> opens the external viewer (the exact command is `txs:///view-pdf-external`) while on my keymap, it is the closing brace.

Comment: Problem has been solved in TeXStudio v2.12.2: external pdf viewer shortcut is editable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem can be resolved in current version of TeXstudio, as noted in the comments.