# TeXStudio: Can’t disable shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Space

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

I use the French keyboard bépo for my typing. Unfortunately this makes heavy use of AltGr as dead key, and consequently it interferes with a lot of shortcuts in TeXStudio. Whilst I’ve been able to disable most of them using the method outlined in [2], the environment shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Space is causing me trouble.  I’ve found the environment entry in the settings (Shortcuts > LaTeX > Environments > \begin{}), but that only shows Ctrl+E as the shortcut.

I’m really confused because it’s never done this before.  I had to reset to factory settings recently because of an issue with compiling, so maybe that caused it.  How do I fix it?

Related questions

[1] [TeXStudio: disable internal shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+X)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349171/texstudio-disable-internal-shortcut-ctrlaltx)

[2] [TeXstudio disable character shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+U)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262703/texstudio-disable-character-shortcut-ctrlaltu)

Comment: if you go to the options->shortcuts, the shortcut you want to disable can be found at "menus/idefix/complete/begin completion"

Comment: Thank you! That’s solved it.

Comment: @Troy Would you mind putting that in an answer, so that I can mark this issue as solved?

Answer (score 3):

User @Troy has posted an answer in the comments to the original question. The shortcut is at "menus/idefix/complete/begin completion" .